# Failed to build android project using gradle

Tags: android, build, gradle

I am having trouble building a simple android project using Gradle. My build file is below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      // To use a development snapshot version of the plugin, add the
      // Sonatype Snapshots repository.
      maven {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
      }
    }

    dependencies {
      classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-android-plugin:1.2.1'
    }
  }

  apply plugin: 'android'

  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
  }

  // Sets the package version
  version = "1.0.0"



  // Signing configuration, valid for all builds (1)
  androidSignAndAlign {
    keyStore = "path/to/my/keystore"
    keyAlias = "my-key-alias"
    keyStorePassword = "mystorepass"
    keyAliasPassword = "myaliaspass"
  }

  // Configure the filtering of resources with properties from the Gradle's project scope (2)
  processResources {
    expand (project.properties)
  }

  // Configure a dedicated debug build (3)
  task configureDebug << {
    jar.classifier = "debug"
  }

  // Configure a dedicated release build (4)
  task configureRelease << {
    proguard.enabled = true
  }
```

The error i get is this:

```
  11:08:24.812 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
11:08:24.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
11:08:24.829 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Where:
11:08:24.834 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Build file 'C:\Users\Work\AndroidProjects\RssUnified\build.gradle' line: 114
11:08:24.840 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
11:08:24.845 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
11:08:24.850 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred evaluating root project 'RssUnified'.
11:08:24.855 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > For input string: "21 rc11"
11:08:24.864 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
11:08:24.870 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
11:08:24.875 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'RssUnified'.
11:08:24.880 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFac
tory.java:54)
11:08:24.885 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.jav
a:127)
```

using gradle 1.2

edit: here is my layout xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the actvivity

```
public class RssListActivity extends Activity {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_activity_layout);
    }

}
```

Project structure below:

```
├───.gradle
│   └───1.2
│       └───taskArtifacts
├───assets
├───bin
│   ├───classes
│   │   └───com
│   │       ├───jr
│   │       │   ├───screenLogic
│   │       │   └───screens
│   │       └───richy
│   │           └───rssunified
│   └───res
├───build
│   └───gen
│       └───com
│           └───richy
│               └───rssunified
├───gen
│   └───com
│       └───richy
│           └───rssunified
├───res
│   ├───drawable-hdpi
│   ├───drawable-ldpi
│   ├───drawable-mdpi
│   ├───drawable-xhdpi
│   ├───layout
│   ├───values
│   ├───values-v11
│   └───values-v14
└───src
    └───com
        └───jr
            ├───screenLogic
            └───screens
```

Here is what is in the root folder of the project

```
AndroidManifest.xml  assets  bin  build  build.gradle  gen  gradle.properties  ic_launcher-web.png  local.properties  project.properties  res  src
```

And finaly the android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.richy.rssunified"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Local.properties

```
sdk.dir = C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk
```

project.properties

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-15
```

edit:

i have reverted back to older version of the adt/sdk plugins and managed to fix the issues above, however after i did that, i now get the above error below:

```
15:24:24.558 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :androidProcessResources FAILED
15:24:24.571 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
15:24:24.575 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
15:24:24.582 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
15:24:24.588 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
15:24:24.597 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':androidProcessResources'.
15:24:24.602 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Unexpected internal error near index 1
15:24:24.607 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   \
15:24:24.613 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ^
15:24:24.621 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
15:24:24.626 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
15:24:24.631 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':androidProcessResources'.
15:24:24.636 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecu
ter.java:68)
```

Comment: People would feel more inclined to help you if you would accept answers to the other questions you asked over the past couple of days.

Comment: I do but it doesnt make an difference, i think this issue is not an easy one to answer. Also, when people add comments not answers, i cant accept them. it has to be posted as an answer. i have gotten answers from people simply just posting a comment

Comment: To be fair, some of my questions i did not find a valid answer so its difficult for me to accept one but for now i will try and accept more. i will accept a valid answer here that works for the issue i am having

Comment: find my gradle version:
In Android Studio, go to File > Project Structure. Then select the "project" tab on the left. If you are using the Gradle wrapper, then your project will have a gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties folder. This determines which version of Gradle you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As is described in:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/using-the-new-build-system#TOC-Working-with-and-Customizing-SourceSets

> Default sourceset location is under `src/<sourceset>`

Your `sourceset` name is `main` so location is `src/main`

Additionally, `manifest` property is described:

> manifest, type AndroidSourceFile, default location `src/<sourceset>/AndroidManifest.xml`

I guess that declaration of manifest:

```
   manifest {
                srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            }
```

is same as default and ends up with location:

```
src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
```

which is listed in exception message.

I think this is how gradle android plugin works.
Correct me if I'm wrong, I don't know Gradle.

### EDIT

Ok, now I know what's wrong. Your build script mixes settings from two different plugins.

Change:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.1'
```

to

```
classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-android-plugin:1.2.1'
```

Remove `android` block, but keep the body.

Remove `sourceSets` block with body.

Then it should work, I tested it this time.

### EDIT 2

This is Windows related bug, fixed 6 days ago:

https://github.com/jvoegele/gradle-android-plugin/pull/89

that what you can do is to download latest plugin version

```
git clone git://github.com/jvoegele/gradle-android-plugin.git
```

and install it in local maven repository:

```
gradle install
```

then add `mavenLocal()` to repositories:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
```

and change plugin version to the snapshot:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-android-plugin:1.2.2-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Comment: Looks like the case. But if i move the directories and the manifest there, i can no longer locally build it via eclipse as it complains about misisng src files, res files and manifest files due to the fact that moving all content under src/main dismantles the default android structure.

Cant i specifi the sourceset location?

Comment: Ok cool. i am no longer geting that error anymore but i now get this error:

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'RssUnified'.
> For input string: "21 rc11"

let me update my question

Comment: It's probably different problem. I don't know what is in `RssUnified\build.gradle' line: 114`. It seems to be connected with latest ADT.

Comment: Line 114 is "  apply plugin: 'android'"

Comment: This build script works for me. I have ADT 20.0.3 - latest stable, and not ADT 21 release candidate 11. Try to delete this package and install latest with SDK Manager.

Comment: Cheers i got passed this error now but getting another error saying how the '\' causes a java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:

This is fustrating. i fix one issue and another one develops. never ending. updating original post

Comment: I get a fatal error saing it is unable to connect to github.com using the command git clone git://github.com/jvoegele/gradle-android-plugin.git from command line in windows 7. might be a proxy issue on my end at work. only thing i can do is try at home.

i will keep u posted and if all goes well i will accept your answer. you have been a real help to me thanks. really appreciate it.

edit: is there another method i can grab latest android plugin manually?

Comment: There're different ways to download it, ex. zip. Try first `git https://github.com/jvoegele/gradle-android-plugin' if failed then open the link in browser and download zip file.

Comment: I managed to get the zip file from here https://github.com/jvoegele/gradle-android-plugin and when i ran the build, it said it could not find the classpath snapshot i defined on my build.gradle from your example.

i unzipped the plugin, navigated into the folder from cmd and typed gradle install and that installed fine.

 Could not find group:org.gradle.api.plugins, module:gradle-android-plugin, version:1.2.2-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: If plugin build succeed it should be visible in maven local repository folder: `.m2/repository/org/gradle/api/plugins/gradle-android-plugin`. Do you have maven2 installed? Check it and repository.

Comment: yea its all there under C:\Users\richardsj\.m2\repository\org\gradle\api\plugins\gradle-android-plugin\1.2.2-SNAPSHOT Do i need to specify on my build where my local repo is located?

Comment: edit. it works. well goes past that issue and now another pops up!

Shall i just accept your answer and create a new question?

now getting "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':androidPackage'.
> apply returned: 1"

Comment: Rather yes, that's lot of questions in one. I don't even use or know Gradle, I was learning it with you :)

Comment: Hehe thanks u have been great help to me. Really appreciate it. If u would like to stay in touch, send me a private message or something and i can send u my email or google+ link

Comment: No problem :) I have some contact details in profile. I see that bounty's gone :(

Comment: yea blooming bounty did not last long .think u replied over the weekend as well and dont tend to code during weekend :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if you are trying to incorrectly escape a backslash in one of your Android resource files as indicated by the task `androidProcessResources`. Please check your resource files or post them here so we can have a look at them.

Comment: Hi there.

My res layout file contains one xml file that just creates a relativeLayout.

i basically created a brand new project and created a blank Activy with a simple layout just to see if i can build and create a apk fil e using gradle. check my edited posts for these files

Comment: Do you have the project uploaded to a repository so I can try it out myself?

Comment: Nope its on my local machine

Comment: Hi, i have updated my code and tried and tweaked a few things and the original error message about the "/" is gone. i know have a different build error stating how the AndroidManifest cant be located

Comment: As the error message states I guess the file needs to be in this location: `C:\Users\richardsj\Work\AndroidProjects\RssUnified\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Yes i can always hack it and move that file there to see if it works, however this is not the correct location in regards to keeping with the structure and guidlines for creating a Android project.

The AndroidManifest is suppose to be inside the root directory of the project, outside of the src folder

Comment: @BenjaminMuschko  Why would anybody put their AndroidManifest.xml in src/main?  AndroidManifest.xml always belongs at the top of one's android project tree.