# Gradle Build Failed: "occurred evaluating root project...failed to create a task or type gettype"

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I am following the basic Gradle Android tutorial here: https://github.com/jvoegele/gradle-android-plugin

But get the following error when running gradle assemble:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'MyAndroidApp'.
> Problem: failed to create task or type gettype
  Cause: The name is undefined.
  Action: Check the spelling.
  Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
  Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

The code in my build.gradle file is:

```
  1 buildscript {
  2   repositories {
  3     mavenCentral()
  4   }
  5 
  6   dependencies {
  7     classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-android-plugin:1.2.1'
  8   }
  9 }
 10 
 11 apply plugin: 'android'
 12 repositories {
 13   mavenCentral()
 14 }
 15 
 16 version = "1.0.1"
 17 
 18 androidSignAndAlign {
 19   // skip signing configuration
 20 }
 21 
 22 // Configure filtering resources with properties from Gradle's project scope
 23 processResources {
 24   expand (project.properties)
 25 }
 26 
 27 // Configure the debug build
 28 task configureDebug << {
 29   jar.classifier = "debug"
 30 }
 31 
 32 // Configure the release build
 33 task configureRelease << {
 34   proguard.enabled = true
 35 }
```

and my project structure is:

```
├── AndroidManifest.xml
├── ant.properties
├── bin
├── build.gradle
├── build.xml
├── libs
├── local.properties
├── proguard-project.txt
├── project.properties
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── my
        │       └── android
        │           └── package
        │               └── MyAndroidActivity.java
        └── res
            ├── layout
            │   └── main.xml
            └── values
                └── strings.xml

11 directories, 10 files
```

I found the below question that seems to be similar, but the fixes don't work:
[Failed to build android project using gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142289/failed-to-build-android-project-using-gradle)

I am very curious not just how to fix the problem but also how to debug it (the stack traces are note as helpful as I hoped).

Comment: I suggest trying to use the official Google-supported Gradle plugin. It will end up being the default build system going forward. http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

Comment: Thanks Greg, using the official Google supported plugin and everything is working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else having the same issue, as Greg mentioned above, switching to the official Google Android Gradle plugin should work:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

There are a number of other questions that I believe were using the unofficial version in this question since it comes up high on search results when searching for the Android Gradle plugin.